# Combining 2 Queries in One Answer (Same Table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, jdbc

I am trying to combine the results from these two queries into the same answer. The If exists is giving me issues when I try to combine them. How would I do this?

Query 1

```
IF EXISTS (select * from jobs where status='BUILDING' and Type='SLA' and Machine_Name=
'SLA1')
BEGIN
    select * from jobs where status='BUILDING' and Type='SLA' and Machine_Name='SLA1'
END
ELSE
  select top 1 * from jobs where Scheduled_Time = (select min(Scheduled_Time) from Jobs 
  where status='IDLE' and type='SLA' and Machine_Name='SLA1')
```

Query 2

```
if exists (select * from jobs where status='BUILDING' and Type='SLA' and Machine_Name=
'SLA3')
BEGIN
   select * from jobs where status='BUILDING' and Type='SLA' and Machine_Name='SLA3'
END 
ELSE
```

These queries aren't related and I don't want them to be interdependent. I was wondering if there is some way to connect them similar to something like a union statement so it just displays the multiple queries in one result.

Answer (score 1):

Change all instances of

```
and Machine_name = 'SLA1'  -- or 3
```

to

```
and machine_name in ('SLA1', 'SLA3')
```

Comment: I appreciate the input. However, this query isn't working because if one machine, say SLA3 has status that is IDLE and SLA1 machine has status that is BUILDING, it only shows SLA1 because the two machines are connected in the if exists statement. Can these queries be separate and be combined by a simple keyword such as JOIN or AND?

Comment: Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM jobs 
    WHERE status = 'BUILDING' AND Type = 'SLA' 
      AND (Machine_Name = 'SLA1' OR Machine_Name = 'SLA3')
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM jobs 
    WHERE status = 'BUILDING' AND Type = 'SLA' 
      AND (Machine_Name = 'SLA1' OR Machine_Name = 'SLA3')
END
ELSE
  SELECT TOP 1 * 
  FROM jobs 
  WHERE Scheduled_Time = 
  (
    SELECT MIN(Scheduled_Time) 
    FROM Jobs 
    WHERE status = 'IDLE' AND type = 'SLA' 
      AND (Machine_Name = 'SLA1'  OR Machine_Name = 'SLA3')
  )
```

Comment: I appreciate your input. However, this doesn't work how I would like it to. The or statement causes it not to reach the else statement when the status is not building for one of the machine types (for example sla3 isn't building) but SLA1 is.

Comment: Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated!